# Show a SQL interogation in a custom block in Drupal

Tags: php, sql, drupal, block

i have problems when i'm trying to display the result of the following query:

```
    SELECT COUNT(`entity_id` ) icount, `field_tags_tid`, `taxonomy_term_data`.`name`
    FROM  `field_data_field_tags` 
    INNER JOIN `taxonomy_term_data` 
    ON `taxonomy_term_data`.`tid`=`field_data_field_tags`.`field_tags_tid`
    GROUP BY `field_tags_tid`
    ORDER BY icount DESC 
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

in a custom block in Drupal.

Here is my my_tags.module file:

```
    <?php
    function my_tags_block_info() {
       $blocks = array();

      $blocks['my_first_block'] = array(
        'info' => t('My custom block'),
        // DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE will be assumed.
      );

      return $blocks;
    }


    function my_tags_block_view($delta = '') {
     if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
        $nid = arg(1);
      };
      $block = array();
      switch ($delta) {
        case 'my_first_block':
          $result = db_query('SELECT COUNT(`entity_id` ) icount, `field_tags_tid`,         `taxonomy_term_data`.`name`
            FROM  `field_data_field_tags` 
            INNER JOIN `taxonomy_term_data` 
    ON `taxonomy_term_data`.`tid`=`field_data_field_tags`.`field_tags_tid`
    GROUP BY `field_tags_tid`
    ORDER BY icount DESC 
    LIMIT 0 , 10');
  $list = array(
    '#theme' => 'links',
    '#links' => array(),

  );
  foreach ($result as $record) {
    $list['#links'][] = array('title' => $record->name , 'name' => $record->icount);
  }
  $block['subject'] = t('Popular tags');
  $block['content'] = $list;
  break;
      }

      return $block;
    }

    ?>
```

And as a result it is shown only the 'name' field, but i need and the 'icount' field.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved my problem this way:

```
  function my_tags_block_view($delta = '') {

    $block = array();
    switch ($delta) {
      case 'my_first_block':
        $result = db_query('SELECT COUNT(`entity_id` ) icount, `field_tags_tid`,             `taxonomy_term_data`.`name`, `revision_id`
    FROM  `field_data_field_tags` 
    INNER JOIN `taxonomy_term_data` 
    ON `taxonomy_term_data`.`tid`=`field_data_field_tags`.`field_tags_tid`
    GROUP BY `field_tags_tid`
    ORDER BY icount DESC 
    LIMIT 0 , 10');


  foreach ($result as $record) {

    $list[] = l($record->name, 'taxonomy/term/'.$record->field_tags_tid);

  }
  dpm($list);

  $block['subject'] = t('Popular tags');
  $block['content'] = theme('item_list', array('items' => $list));;
  break;
    }
```